# Prototype applied for only one object

Tags: javascript, prototype

I just got a little problem in my code.

I've 3 objects defined by a 'class' and when I call this method, it's only executing for the first object.

```
Box.prototype.hit = function() {

    if (controller.space) {
        // Si player détectée en diagonal
        if (this.id - 12 === player.id) {
            console.log(this);
            // Décalage en diagonale de la position de la box
            this.x += this.boxWidth;
            this.y += this.boxHeight;
            currentLevel[this.id] = 0;
            this.id += 12;
            currentLevel[this.id] = 2;
        }
        controller.space = false;
    }
}
```

In this code, the second if is testing the id of the first object defined and the others are not spotted. However I have prototypes like this which are working.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please show us a working example of how this method is called on objects that demonstrates the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Assuming you have one instance on which you call the method, what other objects are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

When I called the method I wrote up there, the id test is not working with all objects owned by the class, except the FIRST object defined. So the console.log return the first object when the player is at the good position of it, but no more with the second and the third objects defined as owned by the class.